# React Native Expo FlatList onPress() doesnt work

Tags: react-native, expo, listitem, flatlist

So I am using Expo and `react-navigation` along with `ListItem` from `react-native-elements` to create a `FlatList` that renders the names of doctors and I want the user to be able to click on a "Know More" button inside the `ListItem` which then navigates to a new screen containing information about the doctor. I am able to render the `FlatList` and have added an `Alert` on clicking the "Know more" button for testing purposes but the weird bug I get is that I have a total of 8 `ListItems` and the `Alert` shows up only on the last (i.e. the 8th) `ListItem` and does not work on the other elements.

Here's all my code from `FindDocScreen`:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBar,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
} from "react-native";

import MyHeader from "../components/MyHeader";

import { ListItem, Avatar } from "@rneui/themed";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";

import { RFValue } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";

const list = [
  {
    name: "Dr. Ashok Mahato",
    avatar_url: "https://api.lorem.space/image/face",
    subtitle: "General Medicine",
    rating: 4.2,
  },
  {
    name: "Dr. Tapan Kumar",
    avatar_url: "https://api.lorem.space/image/face",
    subtitle: "Cardiologist",
    rating: 4.5,
  },
  {
    name: "Dr. Reyaz Ahmed",
    avatar_url: "https://api.lorem.space/image/face",
    subtitle: "Neurologist",
    rating: 3.9,
  },
  {
    name: "Dr. Poonam Singh",
    avatar_url: "https://api.lorem.space/image/face",
    subtitle: "Opthalmologist",
    rating: 4,
  },
  {
    name: "Dr. Nikhilesh Kundu",
    avatar_url: "https://api.lorem.space/image/face",
    subtitle: "Dermatologist",
    rating: 3.8,
  },
  {
    name: "Dr. Manoj Kumar",
    avatar_url: "https://api.lorem.space/image/face",
    subtitle: "Psychiatrist",
    rating: 4.1,
  },
  {
    name: "Dr. Abhik Chatterjee",
    avatar_url: "https://api.lorem.space/image/face",
    subtitle: "Surgeon",
    rating: 4.6,
  },
  {
    name: "Dr. Ranjan Kumar",
    avatar_url: "https://api.lorem.space/image/face",
    subtitle: "Gynecologist",
    rating: 3.8,
  },
];

magicWork = () => {
  
};

const keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();

const renderItem = ({ item, i, navigation }) => {
  return (
    <ListItem
      key={i}
      linearGradientProps={{
        colors: ["#6b79e4", "#7380f0"],
        start: { x: 1, y: 0 },
        end: { x: 0.2, y: 0 },
      }}
      ViewComponent={LinearGradient}
      style={styles.doc}
      containerStyle={{ borderRadius: 20 }}
      bottomDivider
    >
      <Avatar
        rounded
        title={item.name[0]}
        source={item.avatar_url && { uri: item.avatar_url }}
      />
      <ListItem.Content>
        <ListItem.Title style={{ color: "white", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
          {item.name}
        </ListItem.Title>
        <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ color: "white" }}>
          {item.subtitle} - {item.rating} ★
        </ListItem.Subtitle>
      </ListItem.Content>
      <ListItem.Content right={true}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => {
            //navigation.replace("Details", { data: item });
            Alert.alert("Click", "Clicked button");
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Know More</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </ListItem.Content>
    </ListItem>
  );
};

export default class FindDocScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
          barStyle="dark-content"
          hidden={false}
          backgroundColor="#f8f8f8"
          translucent={true}
        />
        <MyHeader />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Top doctors ★</Text>
        <FlatList
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: RFValue(60) }}
          keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
          data={list}
          renderItem={renderItem}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#e9ecf7",
  },

  heading: {
    fontSize: RFValue(27),
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#fff",
    alignSelf: "center",
  },

  text: {
    fontSize: RFValue(30),
    marginLeft: RFValue(15),
    marginTop: RFValue(20),
    color: "#000",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },

  doc: {
    marginTop: RFValue(60),
    width: "88%",
    height: RFValue(18),
    alignSelf: "center",
  },

  button: {
    width: RFValue(85),
    height: RFValue(30),
    backgroundColor: "#e9ecf7",
    borderRadius: 50,
    alignSelf: "center",
    textAlign: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },

  buttonText: {
    fontSize: RFValue(11),
    alignSelf: "center",
    color: "#000",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of your `renderItem` function seems wrong. The signature of this function is [documented in the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) and is as follows:

> renderItem({ item, index, separators });

There is no `navigation` object that is passed to this function. Furthermore, if you destructure properties from an object, then the defined names of the corresponding keys must match. It is called `index` not `i`. Thus, there might be an issue with the `key` property that you are passing to `ListItem`.

Hence,

```js
const renderItem = ({ item, i, navigation })
```

is invalid.

We need to change it to the following.

```js
const renderItem = ({ item, index })
```

Furthermore, it seems odd that your using a `key` prop and a `keyExtractor` at the same time. It might be worth a try to choose only one of these options.

##### Navigation

The `navigation` object will be passed to screens that are defined as components inside of a navigator. This is [documented here in the official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation).

Thus, we have a few options here to make this object accessible to the `renderItem` function.

If `FindDocScreen` is a screen defined in a navigator, then we can pass it to this function directly.

```js
renderItem={({item, index}) => renderItem(item, index, this.props.navigation)}
```

You need to change the signature of your `renderItem` function to the following.

```js
const renderItem = (item, index, navigation ) => {
    ....
}
```

If `FindDocScreen` is not a screen in the navigator, then you can [access the navigation object anyway](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/).

For `react functional components`, this is easy using the `useNavigation` hook. Since your component does not provide any special reason for being a class component, I would convert it to a functional component and would use this hook instead.

```js
export default function FindDocScreen(props) {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
          barStyle="dark-content"
          hidden={false}
          backgroundColor="#f8f8f8"
          translucent={true}
        />
        <MyHeader />
        <Text style={styles.text}>Top doctors ★</Text>
        <FlatList
          contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: RFValue(60) }}
          keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
          data={list}
          renderItem={renderItem={({item, index}) => renderItem(item, index, navigation)}}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, so I tried all the stuff you said but now as I open the screen, I get the error saying `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`.

Here is my updated code:
https://pastebin.com/hpBNLSb9

Comment: Your code ist very different from mine. I suggest that you take a second look at my answer!

Comment: hey im really sorry to bother you but this was all I could get out of your answer. Any chance you might be able to edit the code I provided(the pastebin link) and show me? Would be easier to understand for me as to which approach you’re going for.